# Find number of weeks in a month

Tags: python, week-number

Can someone suggest a function to return number of weeks in a month?
for example:

```
def num_of_weeks(year, month):
    # Do calulation
    return int(num)

# In 2016 Julay we had five weeks
print num_of_weeks(2016, 1)
>> 5

print num_of_weeks(2016, 5)
>> 6
```

Comment: How you define the number of weeks in a month?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using *calendar* built-in module. My example looks hackish, but still it handles your task:

```
def num_of_weeks_in_month(year, month):
    import calendar
    return calendar.month(year, month).count('\n') - 2

print num_of_weeks_in_month(2016, 8)  # print 5
print num_of_weeks_in_month(2016, 9)  # print 5
print num_of_weeks_in_month(2016, 10)  # print 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another mathematical solution:

```
def num_of_weeks_in_month(year, month):
    from math import ceil
    from calendar import monthrange

    return int(ceil(float(monthrange(year, month)[0]+monthrange(year,month)[1])/7))
```